# BEC in two-level system

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, bose-einstein-condensate

Let's take an energy level density function for a particle as $\rho(E)=const {V} {\delta(E-\varepsilon)}$, $V$ is a gas volume, $\delta(E-\varepsilon)$ - delta-function, $\varepsilon$ -  energy level of excited particle (it is not as usual $\rho(E)\sim E^{\frac{d-2}{2}}$). It means that particles in this exotic gas can be  only on two energetic levels - ground -  with the energy $E_0=0$, and excited - $E=\varepsilon$ with degeneracy proportional to $V$ which in termodynamic limit goes with the number of particles $N$ to infinity so that the particle density $n=N/V$ would remain constant. To define critical temperature $1 /{\beta_c}$ we have:

$$N_0+\int_0^\infty \frac{\rho(E)dE}{e^{\beta E}-1}=N,$$

where $N_0$ - the number of particles in ground state. So,  for critical particle density $n_c$ instead 0f well-known power dependence $n_c{\sim}(1/{\beta_c})^{d/2} $ `we have:
$$n_c\sim\frac {1}{e^{\beta_c\varepsilon } -1}$$

> Question: Are there physical systems or theoretical models, with such a "two-level condensation"?
>
> I would also be grateful for the rationale behind the lack of physical sense of the proposed model, if any.

P.S. I would like to emphasize that we have not two states - one ground and one excited, but one ground  and *infinitely many* (in the thermodynamic limit)  excited states with the same energy $\varepsilon$. And in each of the infinite number of excited states there can be an infinite(bosons!) number of particles Two states would be in case of $V\equiv1$

P.P.S. Of course, this model can be formulated without a transition to continuum energy, integration, delta-function, etc. Within the framework of a discrete model without reference to an ideal gas model, this looks like this: $N$ indistinguishable particles can be placed in a $G + 1$ cells, in one of the cells they  have zero energy (be in the ground state), in the all other $G$ cells they have the same  energy $\varepsilon$. If we introduce the particle density in the "space of cells" $n=N/G$ (the mean number of particles in a cell) and thermodynamical limit ($N, G \to\infty$, $n=const$ ) then for the critical density $n_c$ we have:
$$n_c =\frac {1}{e^{\beta_c\varepsilon } -1}$$

P.P.P.S.   Mathematically, the proposed model is closely related to the well-known mathematical problem of the number of weak compositions of the integer $n$, i.e. the number of odered partitions of integer $n$  into exactly $G$ parts allowing them  to be zero:
$${\displaystyle {n+G-1 \choose G-1}}$$
So for the canonical partition function (the number of particles N fixed) we have:

$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N}\dfrac{(n+G-1)!}{n!(G-1)!}\exp({-\beta\varepsilon}n)$$

And for grand сanonical partition function:

$$\frac{1}{1-z}(\frac{1}{1-ze^{-\beta\epsilon }})^G$$

where $z=e^{\beta \mu}$ is fugacity.

IMHO  this is the simplest model, demonstrating the main essence of BEC

**P.P.P.P.S.** Interesting detail, if we replace "quantum stat.weight" in this model:
$${\displaystyle {n+G-1 \choose G-1}}$$

on "(semi)classical" one (whithout $1/n!$) :
$$G^n,$$
we get a   *molecular zipper model* introduced by C.Kittel in 1969 ([https://wwwusers.ts.infn.it/~milotti/Didattica/Biophysics/handouts/Kittel_1969.pdf](https://wwwusers.ts.infn.it/%7Emilotti/Didattica/Biophysics/handouts/Kittel_1969.pdf))

Comment: Normally, condensation is defined as the presence of a macroscopic fraction of the population in a single state out of a continuum. In a two-level system, this is always the case even at infinite temperature, so how are you defining condensation in that case?

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty:  I don't understand your question: we have energy  level with infinite degeneracy, so we have continuum exited states and single ground state

Comment: No, that's not what "continuum" means - you don't seem to understand the model you have postulated. The density of states $\delta(E-\varepsilon)$ describes a single state at energy $\varepsilon$. You can have a macroscopic population on your single excited state, but that still doesn't turn it into a continuum of states (in the same way that in standard BECs having a macroscopic population in the ground state does not mean you have a continuum of ground states). As currently written, the question is fundamentally ill-posed and essentially unanswerable.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty:  "The density of states δ(E−ε) describes a single state at energy ε" -no, not a state but energy level. How we define the number of states? We divide phase volume of the system 0n $2{\pi}h$. Since we have single momentum(energy) so the number of states of the particle would be $(1*V)/(2{\pi}h)$ i.e. infinite in thermodynamic limit

Comment: ...And in each of the infinite number of excited states there can be an infinite(bosons!) number of particles

Comment: If you want to plow on with an ill-posed question and hope that works out, then good for you. However, the definition you've used, from naive thermodynamics, is not applicable to the two-level system you want to work with - for one, since the phase volume of the state manifold is zero, your definition would give you zero states, and more damningly $1\times V/h$ is not dimensionless, so it can't be a "number of states". You need to formulate this from the Hilbert space up, and you need to define what you mean by condensation or the question is meaningless and unanswerable.

Comment: Ok, I agree, that $V$ сan hardly be identified with the physical volume, let it be the number of *energy cells* with the same energy $\varepsilon$, which tends to infinity with $N$ so that $(N/V)=n$ is constant. Sorry for discussion, these were attempts to explain...

Comment: As I said, if you want to plow on with a fundamentally flawed question, or hide the fundamental confusion inside hand-wavy empty concepts like "energy cells", you're welcome to do that. I have indicated why it's ill-posed but if you are unwilling to listen then there's nothing else I can do here.

Comment: This post (v21) seems like a list question.

Comment: Hello Alexsey. Please prefer making fewer, more substantial edits to your question rather than many minor edits; editing your post bumps other people's contributions off of the front page.  Interesting question.

Comment: @rob OK this is the last